Data set not created for firebase analytics and Bigquery integration,
I recently linked my Firebase project with Google Big Query. My Firebase project has an active Android and iOS app and I can successfully retrieve data.
When I exported Crashlytics, Performance monitoring and Cloud messaging, the data sets were instantly created and I can see them in Bigquery.
However for Firebase Analytics, I see a message 'Data set not created' from the integration settings in firebase.
I first activated the integration 2 days ago, and upgraded the billing earlier today. I also added Bigquery permissions to the firebase service accounts.
Help on how to retrieve analytics data in big query would be appreciated





You can try to unlink and relink Firebase and BigQuery again. If that doesn't work, reach out to Firebase support.

Have you tried to link it via Google Analytics 4? I would recommend to disable BigQuery integration in Firebase Console and do it in Google Analytics 4 interface. It is also possible that you have two integrations activated (from Firebase and GA4 interface) and this could end up like this. How to activate integration from GA4 interface? See it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en
